# Redmi 2 Prime stuck on boot screen

Tags: google

I installed [SuperSu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu) on my Redmi 2 Prime via *Stock recovery mode*.
After that ES file manager asked me for root permission, which I accepted. After reboot my phone got stuck on Xiaomi Mi logo boot screen.
I can no longer enter recovery mode. When I try to connect my phone to PC, fastboot command wont detect my phone even though I installed all necessary drivers.
What can I do to repair my phone? Please help me!

Comment: Are you able to access recovery menu or fastboot menu (that dog doctor menu). If not then there's another slight complex way to get your phone back to work

Answer (score 0):

If you can't enter recovery mode or fastboot, I'm afraid you've just hard bricked the phone, and there is nothing you can do now.

Time to buy a new phone.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are from India and you do have your warranty left(I guess). You can give it to your nearest service center and pay some amount to fix it(If they find out that your device is rooted, but in my case they didn't find it so I got a free fix).

I hope this helps! Good Luck!